# The equation of motion(EOM) of rotation of couple moment of magnet bar which rotation axis is fixed at middle and placed in uniform magnetic fields

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, coupled-oscillators

[image]

The magnet bar which rotation axis itself is fixed at the middle of the bar and the magnet bar is placed in the uniform magnetic fields.

$$  I \left[ \text{kg} \cdot \text{m}^{2}    \right] :=\text{motion of inertia}  $$

$$  N_{\theta_{} }= -  \frac{  \partial U  }{  \partial \theta_{}   }    = -MH \sin\left(\theta_{} \right) \left[ \text{N} \cdot m \right] :=\text{couple moment which acts against the magnet bar}  　 $$

The equation of motion of rotation is given as below.

$$  I \frac{  d ^{2} \theta_{}   }{  d  t  ^{2}   }   = -MH \sin\left(\theta_{} \right)   $$

What actually $~ \frac{  d ^{2} \theta_{}   }{  d  t  ^{2}   } \left[ \frac{  1  }{  \text{s}^{2}   }  \right]    ~$ means?

$$  \left[ \text{kg}\cdot \text{} \text{m}^{2}   \right]  \cdot \left[? \right]= \left[ \text{N} \cdot m \right]~~ \leftarrow~~ \text{I wanted to find out the unit of } ~\frac{  d ^{2} \theta_{}   }{  d  t  ^{2}   }  $$

$$  \left[ \text{kg}\cdot \text{} \text{m}^{2}   \right]  \cdot \left[? \right]= \left[\left(  \text{kg} \cdot \frac{  \text{m}   }{  \text{s} ^{2}   }  \right) \cdot m \right]  $$

$$ = \left[ \frac{  \text{kg} \cdot \text{m}^{2}   }{  \text{s}^{2}   }  \right]  $$

$$  \therefore ~~ \left[ ? \right] =\left[ \frac{  1  }{  \text{s}^{2}    }  \right]  $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. What actually $~ \frac{  d ^{2} \theta_{}   }{  d  t  ^{2}   } \left[ \frac{  1  }{  \text{s}^{2}   }  \right]    ~$ means?

This is angular acceleration, the change rate of the angular velocity.
$$
 \alpha = \frac{d \omega}{dt} = \frac{d}{dt} \frac{d\theta}{dt} = \frac{d^2\theta}{dt^2}
$$
Since the angle (in radians) is of no unit, therefore the angular acceleration has a unit $\frac{1}{s^2}$.

2. Dimension analysis.  Equation of motion:
   $$  I \frac{  d ^{2} \theta_{}   }{  d  t  ^{2}   }   = -MH \sin\left(\theta_{} \right)   $$
   The right-hand-side is torque of unit $N-m = \frac{Kg-m^2}{s^2} $. In the left-hand-side, the inertial moment $I = kg-m^2$
   Thus
   \begin{align}
   I \alpha &= \tau;\\
    \left(kg-m^2\right) \alpha &= \frac{kg-m^2}{s^2};\\
   \alpha &= \frac{1}{s^2}
   \end{align}